# Collect DOM elements from external HTML documents

Tags: javascript, dom

I am trying to write a report-generator to collect user-comments from a list of external HTML files. User-comments are wrapped in < span> elements.

Can this be done using JavaScript?

Here's my attempt:

```
function generateCommentReport()
{
    var files = document.querySelectorAll('td a'); //Files to scan are links in an HTML table
    var outputWindow = window.open(); //Output browser window for report

    for(var i = 0; i<files.length; i++){
        //Open each file in a browser window
        win = window.open();
        win.location.href = files[i].href;

        //Scan opened window for 'comment's
        comments = win.document.querySelectorAll('.comment');
        for(var j=0;j<comments.length;j++){
            //Add to output report
            outputWindow.document.write(comment[i].innerHTML);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are all the files on the local filesystem?

Comment: yes. all the files are on the local filesystem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I have the solution to this.

```
var windows = [];
var report = null;

function handlerFunctionFactory(i,max){
    return function (evt){
        //Scan opened window for 'comment's
        var comments = windows[i].document.querySelectorAll('.comment');

        for(var j=0;j<comments.length;j++){
            //Add to output report
            report.document.write(comments[j].innerHTML);
        }
        if((i+1)==max){
            report.document.write("</div></body></html>");
            report.document.close();
        }
        windows[i].close();
    }
}

function generateReport()
{
    var files = document.querySelectorAll('td a'); //The list of files to scan is stored as links in an HTML table
    report = window.open(); //Output browser window for report

    report.title = 'Comment Report';
    report.document.open();
    report.document.write('<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC"-// W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"" http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">'
        + '<html><head><title>Comment Report</title>'
        + '</head><body>');

    for(var i = 0; i<files.length; i++){
        //Open each file in a browser window
        win = window.open();
        windows.push(win)
        win.location.href = files[i].href;
        win.onload = handlerFunctionFactory(i,files.length);
    }
}
```

1. Any refactoring tips are welcome. I am not entirely convinced that factory is the best way to bind the onload handlers to an instance for example.
2. This works only on Firefox :(

Answer (score 1):

You will need to wait for `onload` on the target window before you can read content from its document.

Also what type of element is `comment`? In general you can't put a `name` on just any element. Whilst unknown attributes like a misplaced name may be ignored, you can't guarantee that browsers will take account of them for `getElementsByName`. (In reality, most browsers *do*, but IE doesn't.) A `class` might be a better bet?

Comment: have changed from name to class. 
and how can we wait for the onload of the child windows?

Comment: `win.onload= function() {`...do something with contents of window...`};`. You would have to refactor your loop so that it could work asynchronously.

Comment: finished on a firefox-only solution - not sure why it doesn't work on other browsers. seems straightforward enough... :(

Answer (score 0):

Each web browse works in a defined and controlled work space on a user computer where certain things are restrict to code like file system - these are safety standards to ensure that no malicious code from internet runs into your system to phishing sensitive information stored on in it. Only ways a webbrowser is allowed if access granted explicitly by the user.

```
But i can suggest you for Internet Application as

  - If List of commands is static then cache either by XML, Json or Cookies [it will store on user's system until it expires]
  - If dynamic then Ajax to retrieve it
```

Comment: i am relying on explicit access. what i am doing is based on the file:// protocol. check out http://memonaut.googlecode.com